# Overriding Apache-headers with headers from ErrorDocument?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

Is it possible to override the Apache headers from a `.htaccess`-file with headers from the defined `ErrorDocument`?

The background is the following: An user tries to open a file by url that does not exist in the file-system. The `.htaccess`-file forwards the resulting `404`-error to the `index.php`, which will search for contents based on the given url in `path`-parameter. If contents are found, a `200`-status should be override the `404`-error.

In my tests using PHP overriding is not working: I still receive the `404`-status.

1. `index.php`:

   ```
   <?php
   header("HTTP/2.0 200 OK");
   ```
2. `.htaccess`:

   ```
   errorDocument 404 /index.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI}
   ```

Is it somehow possible to "update" and override the previously sent Apache-header?